# how to publish linear velocity and angular velocity rosserial arduino?

Tags: rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to publish linear velocity and angular velocity rosserial arduino with Twist.h ?

I tried

geometry_msgs::TransformStamped t;

t.transform.translation.x = x;
t.transform.translation.y = y;
t.transform.translation.z = 0;

t.transform.rotation = tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(th);
t.Twist.Twist.linear.x=dx/dt;
t.Twist.Twist.linear.z=dth/dt;

but last two lines error

I need your help plz thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276284/how-to-publish-linear-velocity-and-angular-velocity-rosserial-arduino?/) by [nada2bnm](https://answers.ros.org/users/32227/nada2bnm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html), this is the definition of a `geometry_msgs/Twist` message:

```
# This expresses velocity in free space broken into its linear and angular parts.
Vector3  linear
Vector3  angular
```

So to fill it, you only have to set it like this (the same way than within a normal ROS node):

```
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;
msg.linear.x = 1.0;  // m/s
msg.angular.z = 0.5; // rad/s
```

Then you can publish it with your already defined publisher (note that we pass a pointer with `rosserial_arduino`):

```
cmd_pub.publish(&msg);
```

To see an publisher example on `rosserial_arduino`, please, look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World).

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1